# Pointer to element in array of pointers. & result in dereference instead of reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I am relatively inexperienced on C/C++ and (obviously) got confused with pointers.

I have an array of pointers to a structure. I want to initialize a pointer to an element of the array of pointers. I expect to be able to do something like this:

```
struct mystruct **pt = &(structarray[i])
```

VS Code however tells me that the operators are `mystruct` ** and `mystruct`. How is this possible? If I try to write reduced examples, it works as I imagine, but in the code I wrote it does not.

---

If more context is needed, below is the long explanation.
I have a structure like:

```
struct varArray {
  struct varArray *next;
  short unsigned int imin;
  short unsigned int imax;
  struct varNode varNode[1];
};
```

I define a pointer array as a global variable:

```
extern struct varArray *varPlane;
```

Next I initialize all elements of the array to a null pointer:

```
struct varArray * varPlane[nmax];
for (int i = 0; i < nmax; i++) {
 varPlane[i] = nullptr;
}
```

Under some conditions I want a varPlane element to point to a structure that I initialize with malloc. So I would like to do:

```
struct varArray ** temparray =  &(varPlane[INDEX(ix, iy)]);
*temparray = (struct varArray *) malloc(sizeof(struct varArray) + sizeof(struct varNode) * (imax - imin));
```

But the first line doesn't work for the reasons I mentioned above.

I need to use a pointer to the varPlane element because I create a linked list iteratively by doing:

```
temparray=(*temparray)->next
```

Comment: `struct varArray *varPlane` is a pointer to a `varArray`. `struct varArray * varPlane[nmax];` is an array of pointers to `varArray`. These are not the same type.

Comment: First things first, this [won't compile](https://onlinegdb.com/fJL9IiCN1) because type of `varPlane` in the declaration and definition are different.

Comment: There is no such language as `C/C++`.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever teaches you `C++` teaches you `C` - just to be clear on that.
Current best practices are far different between the languages.

These are guidelines, not rules:

1. `C++` allows the use of extern but most of the time is not needed - especially in simple code.
2. Variables are not declared with `struct` you can simply write `varArray* myArr`.
3. We don't use `malloc`, you can use `new`.

This is compiled  (x64 msvc v19.latest):
https://godbolt.org/z/od84coMTz

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct varNode{
    int a;
};

struct varArray {
  varArray *next;
  short unsigned int imin;
  short unsigned int imax;
  varNode node[1];
};

int main()
{
    const auto nmax = 5;

    varArray * plane[nmax];
    for (int i = 0; i < nmax; i++) 
    {
        plane[i] = nullptr;
    }
    varArray ** temparray =  &(plane[1]);
    std::cout << temparray;
}
```

1. You mentioned " `vs code` tells me" - the Intellisense sometimes messes up.
   So please mention what exactly is the `compilation error` and what code doesn't work.
   Use https://godbolt.org/ for sharing the code :)
2. As you see I simplified the C style code to a more C++ manner.
   Hopefully I didn't discard anything important.
   If the case is that you need `C` and not `C++` then most of the pointer semantics are the same just the syntax differs sometimes (Like in the malloc).

Answer (score 0):

First things first the program is invalid and [won't compile](https://onlinegdb.com/fJL9IiCN1) because the type of `varPlane` in the declaration and definition are different. In particular, `extern struct varArray *varPlane` **declares** a pointer named `varPlane` to a `struct` named `varArray`. On the other hand, `struct varArray * varPlane[nmax];` **defines** an array named `varPlane` with size `nmax` and elements of type `varArray*`.

That is, the program is invalid C++.